# Where do we report issues on a new beta site without moderators?

Tags: support, flags, moderation, beta-sites

I've been fairly active in the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange, which recently went to beta.

Earlier this week, my reputation took a hit when some serial upvoting was reversed (which is fine by me; I'd rather earn my rep than get it as a groupie gift).

Problem is, I woke up this morning, only to discover I was apparently serially upvoted again overnight.  About 10 of my questions were upvoted, all within the same hour.

ELL doesn't have moderators yet. As such, I'm not sure how I would flag this, because, unlike an answer or a comment, it's hard to flag an upvote – much less 10 of them.

I'm just wondering what the best course of action would be under such circumstances.

Comment: Get some moderators appointed :-)? Seriously though, there's no need to flag. It gets automatically reversed as you've noticed.

Comment: Moderators like Shog9 and Robert Cataino are still active over there though. So their Meta might be a reasonable place to post such issues.

Comment: @ben: I believe mod appointments are coming soon; this went public only a day or two ago. I'm not so worried about the points being rolled back; I was more concerned with possible "voting irregularities" if this keeps persisting.

Answer (score 6):

The best course of action is still to use a custom moderator flag. Even if there are no appointed/elected ♦ moderators yet, Community Managers (in the recent past, this was usually [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)'s job) will keep an eye on the flag queue. If it's really urgent and one of them is available in the new site's main chatroom, I guess you could ping them to inform them of the flag.